# Copying one vector to Another in least time complexity?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have two vectors old and newone
I want to copy the value of newone into old what would be the fastest method to do so
I think i can use pointers but i also think assigment
**newone = old**
will do the same

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> old = {1,2,3};
    vector<int> newone = {4,5,6};
    
    newone = old;
    for( auto x : newone ){
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
}
```

Are there any methods to do itin 0(1)/constant time ?? besides pointers

Comment: You can't *copy* a vector of size `n` in `O(n)` time. You can *move* it in constant time though.

Comment: `newone = std::move(old);`

Answer (score 0):

Like it was said in comment, you can use move the `vector`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> old = {1,2,3};
    vector<int> newone = {4,5,6};
    
    newone = std::move(old); // 1
  
    for( auto x : newone ){
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
}
```

`std::move` while flag `old` as a temporary, then the copy operator of `vector` will select the overload which takes a temporary and ''steal'' the data of `old`.

Past the `//1`, `old` is in a state call "[moved from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)", basically the object is in a valid state, but you can't suppose anything about this state, you have to check it (by example with `.size()`)

If you want more info about move : [check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

---

**Note:** [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)